# Stop Google indexing subdomains

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt

I have a site that uses wildcard subdomains so that when somebody signs up they get there own subdomain.

I do no want google (or other serach engines) to crawl and index any of the subdomains (accept for www.)

Is there away to do this with robots.txt?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Im guessing no, at least not directly with one global `robots.txt` file. See: http://www.seomoz.org/q/block-an-entire-subdomain-with-robots-txt

Somewhere on that page andykuiper wrote:

> you can block an entire subdomain via robots.txt, however you'll need to create a robots.txt file and place it in the root of the subdomain, then add the code to direct the bots to stay away from the entire subdomain's content.
>
> User-agent: *
>   Disallow: /

See also:

- http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/f5AfW1otAUo
- [Disallow or Noindex on Subdomain with robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904642/disallow-or-noindex-on-subdomain-with-robots-txt)
- [Subdomain disallow search bots via robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803319/subdomain-disallow-search-bots-via-robots-txt)

Make a script that creates/copies the `robots.txt` file to a newly created subdomain and everything should work as intended.